# Can I use Voip Pushkit Notification for just notify the users about other things then a VOiP call

Tags: ios, background, voip

I am developing an application for home automation. Am I use VoIp background execution to listen my server(not for calls) and notify users locally.(ect. turn on/off lights data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can utilise pushkit notification for just notifying user about particular things. then use local notifications. there is no need that it uses only for voip calls.

Another approach, you can utilise websockets, which constantly broadcast data, when it reaches to device you could schedule local notification.

Let me know if you had any trouble in pushkit implementation.

Comment: how can I broadcast data from websockets in backround on ios ?

Comment: Java developer at back end can develop broadcast environment using JavaScript, your socket connection URL (Protocol ) will be like ws:// or wss:// , then at iOS end using https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket you can receive data, any change at server ( on / off ) will be broadcast at iOS end you can listen and do appropriate things. http://www.websocket.org/echo.html